# FUSE recommended error code for file validation errors

Tags: filesystems, fuse

I'm writing a FUSE Filesystem that makes API resources available as files in the system.
Changes made to those files should be sent to the API and update the resources.
I have validation rules that i want to enforce when a file is saved.
I'm wondering which error code to choose.

- EFTYPE
- EPERM
- EACCES
- EIO
- EINVAL
- ENOTSUP
- ENOTTY
- EDOM

Right now i would go with EFTYPE, but i'm not sure if that is common for file systems?
I'm worried about editor support.